# Proving that the sum of a convergent geometric series is greater than 1/2

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am struggling to prove that the sum of a convergent geometric series $1+r+r^{2}+\cdots$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. Here is my attempt:

Let $S=1+r+r^{2}+\cdots$ be the sum of the series.
Multiplying $S$ by $r$, we get $rS=r+r^{2}+\cdots$.
Subtracting the two equations, we get $(1-r)S=1$, so $S=\frac{1}{1-r}$.

To prove that $S>\frac{1}{2}$, we need to show that $\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2}$. This is equivalent to $1-r<\frac{1}{2}$, or $r>\frac{1}{2}$.

However, I am unsure how to proceed from here. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to complete the proof. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $1-r<2\implies r>-1$

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thank you for pointing that out. You are correct that my logic was incorrect. The correct inequality is $1-r>\frac{1}{2}$, which gives $r<\frac{1}{2}$. To see this, note that we want to show that $\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2}$. Multiplying both sides by $2(1-r)$ gives $2>\frac{1-r}{1-r}$, which simplifies to $2>1$. This inequality is always true, so it follows that $\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, we have $S=\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Since $-1<r<1$, you have $0<1-r < 2$ and so ${1 \over 1-r} > {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat How do you go from $-1<r<1$ to $0<1-r<2$? Isn't it $0<1+r<2$? But, using your reasoning, we can multiply both sides of $\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2}$ by $1-r$ to get $2>1-r$. Since $0<1-r<2$, we would conclude that $\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @bittscoterie $-1<r<1$, so $1>-r>-1$.Add 1 : $2>1-r>0$. There you have it.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you explain how you got $0<1-r<2$ to $\dfrac{1}{1-r} > \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: @bobster Divide both sides of $1-r<2$ by $2(1-r)$ (which is positive).

Comment: @bobster See the comment from D S 2 immediately before your comment.

Answer (score 1):

For a geometric series to be convergent
$$ -1 < r < 1 $$
$$ 1 > -r > -1 $$
$$ 2 > 1-r > 0 $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{1-r} < \infty $$
Thus it is greater than $1/2$.