# Proving that the sum of a convergent geometric series $1+r+r^2+ \ldots > 1/2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hello I got stuck on proving that the convergent geometric sum $$1+r+r^2+\ldots > \frac12$$

What I got so far is:

The geometric sum can be seen on the form $a(1-r^n)/1-r$ with $a=1$
and given that it is convergent the sum $= 1/1-r$ and that $|r|<1$ means that $-1 < r < 1$

I saw someone else solve it by going from $-1 < r < 1$ to $0< 1-r < 2$ and then  $1/1-r > 1/2$ can someone explain how they did this last part?

Comment: The function $\frac 1{1-r}$ is strictly increasing from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Which follows from $1-r$ being strictly decreasing.

Comment: Same question asked two days ago, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646657/proving-that-the-sum-of-a-convergent-geometric-series-is-greater-than-1-2

Answer (score 1):

$1-r<1-(-1)=2$ and $1-r >0$  so $\frac 1 {1-r}>\frac 1  2$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=1 + r +r^2+r^3 +...+r^{n-1} = \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$
For $|r|<1$ or $-1<r<1$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S = \frac{1}{1-r}$$
Now as
$$-1<r<1 \implies -1<-r<1 \implies 0<1-r<2 \implies \infty>\frac{1}{1-r}>\frac{1}{2} \implies \frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{1-r}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what i dont seem to grasp is the infinity > 1/1-r > 1/2. How do we get there?

Comment: And why can we remove the infinity part and just say 1/1-r > 1/2

Comment: $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$ and obviously any real number will be less than $\infty$ and that's why you can remove it